# BUG: When asking OpenAI API from curl call, the response is not Limiting responses to my data content. Why?

Tags: azure, openai-api

When asking OpenAI API from **curl** call, the response is not Limiting responses to my data content.

At the same time, using Microsoft's demo (Chat session) it works. I followed their own instructions:

```
POST https://{your-resource-name}.openai.azure.com/openai/deployments/{deployment-id}/completions?api-version=2023-03-15-preview
```

Using Microsoft website, when I ask **"How old is Lady Gaga"**, it correctly says there's no data about it in my deployment data, but when I ask the same using CURL from my server, it answer with her age, and details about her.

**I AM PRETTY SURE we never uploaded anything related to Lady Gaga xD**

Is this OpenAI Service really working outside of Microsoft's demo chatbox?

Why isn't it working only when it's being asked from my server side?

Comment: This is embarrassing. Microsoft is destroying OpenAI reputation.

Comment: Chat with Azure OpenAI models using your own data is available from api-version=2023-06-01-preview, please update to the latest preview versions.

Answer (score 1):

Chat with Azure OpenAI models using your own data is available from api-version=2023-06-01-preview, please update to the latest preview versions. You can use the following [repo](https://github.com/akshata29/chatpdf) to Chat and Ask on your own data. Accelerator to quickly upload your own enterprise data and use OpenAI services to chat to that uploaded data and ask questions.

Comment: It doesn't help to set the api-version to the newest one, as you said. In my case I also tried the version 2023-07-01-preview but not able to access my own data through the REST API however within the Azure AI Studio everything works as aspected.

Answer (score 0):

Below was scraped from the APIs the built-in chat in Azure Open AI makes; and works for now.

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://<AZURE OPEN AI SERVICE>/openai/deployments/<OPEN AI DEPLOYMENT NAME>/extensions/chat/completions?api-version=2023-06-01-preview"

payload = json.dumps({
  "dataSources": [
    {
      "type": "AzureCognitiveSearch",
      "parameters": {
        "endpoint": "https://<SEARCH SVC>.search.windows.net",
        "key": "AZURE COGNITIVE SEARCH KEY",
        "indexName": "index",
        "semanticConfiguration": "default",
        "queryType": "simple",
        "fieldsMapping": {},
        "inScope": True,
        "roleInformation": "You are an AI assistant that helps employees find information on Health instance related information",
        "filter": None,
        "embeddingEndpoint": None,
        "embeddingKey": None
      }
    }
  ],
  "deployment": "HR-Model-gpt35-turbo-16k",
  "temperature": 0,
  "top_p": 1,
  "max_tokens": 200,
  "stop": None,
  "stream": False,
  "messages": [
    {
      "role": "assistant",
      "content": "Hello! How can I assist you today?"
    },
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "hello"
    }
  ]
})
headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'api-key': 'API KEY'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?